# Restore Postgres db.dump file after docker-compose up -d build

Tags: postgresql, docker

I have a restored database which filename is `db.dump`.
I want to restore this database after Postgres container up.

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "2"
services:
  web:
    build: 
      context: ./Server
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    volumes:
      - ./Server/:/home/app/
    depends_on:
  - db
    links:
  - db
  db:
    image: postgres:10
    env_file: .env
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    expose:
      - 5432
```

**.env**

```
POSTGRES_USER=taz
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
POSTGRES_DB=Medicine
```

When i tried id:

```
sudo docker-compose up -d --build
```

and after:

```
sudo docker-compose exec -T db pg_restore -d Medicine -U taz -C < db.dump
```

I have a following error:

**pg_restore: [archiver] input file is too short (read 0, expected 5)**

Comment: Did you find any solution to this?